# Function to change the data in a row of jTable and SAVE changes made into a text file

Tags: java

I've hit a roadblock in my jFrame form programming and no solutions comes up on the internet.

I'm creating a booking system where it requires the User to have the ability to view, book or cancel booking hour slots. I can save a row of code as an array with commas (",") as a means to separate the various types of data (time, place, date etc) into a text file.

I am able to write and read the text file and display it into a jTable. Retrieval is not the problem here, however, as my current problem is clicking on a selected row in the jTable and changing a particular column data with the click of a button and saving it into a text file, replacing the previous line.

I have heard suggestions of using a temp file and deleting the previous text file but I am unable to reproduce that technique into practice.

An example of my JTable structure shows up as follows:

```
|StaffID|EmployeeID|Status   |Location |Time Start |Duration | Date      |
| ID10t | IDidN4Ht |Available|  Here   |   12:30   | 30 min  | 12/3/2020 |
|Lorelai| Gorbachev| Booked  |  There  |   6 BCE   |40  years| 02/02/11  |
```

An example of the data that would be saved in text files is as follows, with commas (",") as delimiter:

```
ID10t,IDidN4Ht,Available,Here,12:30,30 min,12/3/2020
Lorelai,Gorbachev,Booked,There,6 BCE,40 years,02/02/11 
testStaff,-,Available,Room-5A,10:40pm,15mins,13/12/2023
IDqq,ID01,b,Class A,10:30am,15mins,13/11/2023
```

Assuming StaffID in the Jtable && String "test" in the text file = column[0],
what would I need to do if I wanted to click on a Book button that would change column[1]/EmployeeID in the text file from a dash ("-") into the current User's EmployeeID as well as change column[3]/Status from "Available" to "Booked", then save the new data into the text file?

I've tried various BufferedReader and FileWriter methods, tried creating and using an @Override class, but to no results.

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.BufferedWriter;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.FileWriter;

   //I am using Comboboxes to save the data, hence the .getSelectedItem
   //This is the code for the Adding button which I use to write the data into the text file, which is "info.txt"
    String staffid = jLabel1.getText().trim();
    String empid = "-";
    String status = "Available";
    String venue = venueb.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String time = timeb.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String dura = durab.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String date = dateb.getSelectedItem().toString();


    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("info.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter print = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("info.txt");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            print.newLine(); //newLine added so each row will stack
            print.write(staffid);
            print.write(",");
            print.write(empid);
            print.write(",");
            print.write(status);
            print.write(",");
            print.write(venue);
            print.write(",");
            print.write(time);
            print.write(",");
            print.write(dura);
            print.write(",");
            print.write(date);
            print.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Booking Added");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //This is the code I use the Update button to retrieve the data from the text file and display them into the jTable
    table = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    table.setColumnIdentifiers(
            new String[]{"Staff ID","Employee ID","Status","Venue","Time Start",
                "Duration","Date"}
    );
    table.setRowCount(0); //this is to clear the jTable after each click
    try {
        File file = new File("info.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        Object[] Lines = br.lines().toArray();


        for(int i = 1; i < Lines.length; i++)
        {
            String line = Lines[i].toString().trim();
            String[] dataRow = line.split(",");
            table.addRow(dataRow);
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TextFileDataToJTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

As of now, I have left the Book and Cancel Button's code blank. I have been pulling my hair out trying to scour the entire internet trying to find a solution. If someone could help me I would be so grateful

Comment: Seems to me that using a database to store the `JTable` data would be more appropriate than a text file. Do you have to store the data in a text file?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I know SQL would really simplify the process alot

Comment: So basically you are asking how to modify the contents of a text file through java code, correct?

Comment: You are correct. I've thought of using a temp file to store the contents of the rows that are not selected, as well as the row that is selected which is intended to have one of its columns modified. Then renaming the temp file to the original filepath before deleting the original file. If you have any suggestions it would be appreciated

Comment: Have you searched the Internet for the terms _java update file content_ ?

Comment: yes, i have, btw